# Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0 killedMaps:0 killedReduces: 0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have 4 nodes(1 master 3 slave) and running a job. I have a problem. I get error below. I could not resolve. Can you help me?

[Yarn UI Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEnKZ.png)

[Yarn UI Error-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AphV.png)

[Yarn Error All-3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1onYXcwt0Nyl02iB2eOHodyXCDPQrylUQ/view?usp=sharing)

```
2022-07-28 06:16:55,185 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Received completed container container_1658988882858_0001_01_000120
2022-07-28 06:16:55,185 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1658988882858_0001_m_000080_0: [2022-07-28 06:16:54.401]Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
[2022-07-28 06:16:54.414]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2022-07-28 06:16:54.421]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 

2022-07-28 06:16:55,185 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Received completed container container_1658988882858_0001_01_000121
2022-07-28 06:16:55,185 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1658988882858_0001_m_000082_0: [2022-07-28 06:16:54.422]Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
[2022-07-28 06:16:54.432]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2022-07-28 06:16:54.434]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 

2022-07-28 06:16:55,185 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Received completed container container_1658988882858_0001_01_000122
2022-07-28 06:16:55,185 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1658988882858_0001_m_000087_0: [2022-07-28 06:16:54.423]Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
[2022-07-28 06:16:54.432]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2022-07-28 06:16:54.434]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 

2022-07-28 06:16:55,185 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Received completed container container_1658988882858_0001_01_000125
2022-07-28 06:16:55,185 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1658988882858_0001_m_000000_3: [2022-07-28 06:16:54.215]Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
[2022-07-28 06:16:54.310]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2022-07-28 06:16:54.311]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 

2022-07-28 06:16:55,185 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Received completed container container_1658988882858_0001_01_000123
2022-07-28 06:16:55,185 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1658988882858_0001_m_000016_3: [2022-07-28 06:16:54.231]Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
[2022-07-28 06:16:54.348]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2022-07-28 06:16:54.384]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143.
```

Comment: I also see this error. But There is no problem in single server with same configuration.

Comment: Please give the actual error from the YARN UI itself

Comment: @OneCricketeer I add YARN UI Screenshot

Comment: Click the logs link at the bottom. Then find the specific map task that failed. Then look at its logs

Comment: I add YARN UI Error-2. I can't add all the logs. However, I can provide a link. Very happy if you help.

Comment: You've still added the wrong file. If you expand "full log", you need to look for lines that look related to your actual code that would start before any lines that include `failedMaps`

Comment: I add Yarn Error All-3 via drive link. I shared it with the drive because the file size is large.

Comment: You don't need to upload the whole file. I'm just telling you where you need to be looking to find the real error message for the failed mapper. That new file looks like logs from the ApplicationMaster, not a specific map task.